# Why is my ExceptionFilter not fetching exceptions when the site is deployed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC 4 application and I've registered an Exception filter:

Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    // Here my filter gets registered
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

FilterConfig.cs:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleUnhandledExceptionFilter());
    }
}
```

HandleUnhandledExceptionFilter.cs:

```
public class HandleUnhandledExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("An unknown error occured");
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Notice, I **don't** use the WEB API Framework, but I use the MVC filters.

When an exception occurs, I want to display the text `An unknown error occured`. This works fine when I execute the site locally. When I publish the site, copy the published files to the webserver and browse on my machine (which is not the webserver) and get an eception, I dont see the text `An unknown error occured`. Instead I get the source of an error page. So I see literally this:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html .... etc.`

First I thought maybe it has something to do with `customErrors`, so I added a `customErrors` tag to my webconfig:

`<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>`

But unfortunately, this didn't do the trick. So my question is: what do I have to do to show my own error message?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that my filter is catching exceptions and that the 'real' problem was IIS 7. By default, IIS 7 uses it's own (custom) error pages when the Http StatusCode > 400. So in my case IIS 7 used it's own error page. Obviously this was not what I wanted.

Two ways of solving this issue are:

1. Set `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;`. This will tel IIS7 not to use it's own error pages, but to use the `ResponseText`.
2. In the `web.config` in the `system.webServer` element add this line: `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>`.

For more information about this topic, see [What to expect from IIS7 custom error module](http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2008/02/18/what-to-expect-from-iis7-custom-error-module.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display `Error occurred` then you can try this

```
 <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/YOURCONTROLLER/VIEW" />
```

abovecode will redirect to page which you have mention in `defaultredirect`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm only interested in the text. I don't want a redirect. I've tried setting mode to `RemoteOnly`, but it didn't make a difference.